# How to get distance by city + zipCode on google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=PLACE,ZIPCODE&destinations=PLACE,ZIPCODE&sensor=false
```

I need to get distance between two places by place name and zip code. But when I pass parameters separated by "comma" it doesn't work. How to pass this two parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use + to seperate the place name and the zip code:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=NEW+YORK+11535&destinations=WASHINGTON+20544&sensor=false
```

Answer (score 1):

it is also possible to give ONLY the zip code:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=38017|85353&destinations=94109|33128|95117&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: This worked for me. Instead of more Origins/Destinations, you can use only one